# set arangodb environment variable for authentication in bitbucket pipelines file

Tags: python-2.7, docker, arangodb, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm working to use CI on an application I'm working on using bitbucket pipelines file. 
In order to do so I need to import my database docker image (arangodb) and specify some environment variables to set up the authentication method as described [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/arangodb/arangodb/). Short story, it could either be one of those possibilities:

- ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1
- ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1
- ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword

For some reason, running the pipeline with either one of the two first send back the error :

> The 'environment' section in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file must be
>   a map.

I managed to get the pipeline running using the environment variable in the file below, but I may want to change for the other methods at some point. I'm not sure what the problem is actually as writting ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD: '' sends back the same previous error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Python.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/x4UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: python:2.7

pipelines:
  branches:
    '{dev,master}':
        - step:
            script: 
              - python setup.py develop
              - python ./server/kernel/setup.py
              - python ./server/tests/jsonLoginRegister_tests.py 
            services:
              - arangodb   
definitions:
  services:
    arangodb:
      image: arangodb/arangodb
      environment: 
        ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Python.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/x4UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: python:2.7

pipelines:
  branches:
    '{dev,master}':
        - step:
            script: 
              - python setup.py develop
              - python ./server/kernel/setup.py
              - python ./server/tests/common_tests.py 
            services:
              - arangodb   
definitions:
  services:
    arangodb:
      image: arangodb/arangodb
      environment: 
        ARANGO_NO_AUTH: 1
```